# Issue saving a cvs file to a usb drive using node on a raspberry pi

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi2

This one is really doing my head in! please help!

So I have a little raspberry pi 2 running debian and node 0.12.6.

The node script listens to a home automation bus for events and saves these to a json list. This list is then saved to cvs using a cron job hourly (every min for testing) to a usb drive that is mounted at boot on the system.

The issue is that every time fs.writeFile is called it throws an error.

This only happens if I try and save to the usb drive, and not to local folders, which work fine.

I have altered the /etc/fstab file to include the following

```
/dev/sda1       /home/pi/knx/usb        vfat    user,auto,nodev,gid=pi,uid=pi,fmask=0111,dmask=0000    0    0
```

This appears to mount the usb at boot and I can as pi user make dirs and files no problem from the console.

The permissions of the folder (with the usb drive mounted at usb) look like this....

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/knx $ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  965 Nov 20 16:40 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Nov 20 16:00 data_files
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Nov 19 12:27 install_scripts
drwxr-xr-x 7 pi pi 4096 Nov 20 16:21 node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 8 pi pi 8192 Jan  1  1970 usb
```

The drive looks to be mounted ok....

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/knx $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1  15G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1  15G  0 part /home/pi/knx/usb
```

The node script is ...

```js
//set up chron job to save list
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 0-59 * * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    console.log('saving file');
      json2csv({ data: listToSave, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        tempfilename = new Date();
        fname = './usb/data_files/'+ tempfilename.toString() +'.csv';
        console.log(fname);
        fs.writeFile(fname, csv, function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('file saved');
          listToSave=[];
        });
      });
  
  },
  start: true,
});
```

The fname looks like this....

```
'./usb/data_files/Fri Nov 20 2015 16:42:00 GMT+0000 (UTC).csv'
```

If I had any hair - I would have well and truly pulled it out by now!

Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the filename you are creating with "new Date()" is an invalid format for the filesystem. 
I'm able to make your code work by formatting the raw date string into a friendlier file name:

```
var utils = require('util')
```

Above adds the util module for string formatting.

```
var today = new Date();
var fname = utils.format('./usb/%s-%s-%s.csv', today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), today.getHours());
```

This writes a "MM-dd.csv" filename which appears to work on my debian machine. You can extend this by adding the time, year , etc.

Comment: Thank you devduderino! All working fine. Really HUGE thanks